# In python3, what's the difference between defining a class method inside or outside __init__ function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

Example

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def f(self,arg=None):
        if arg: print(arg)
        else: print(self.val)
    @classmethod
    def otherclassmethods(cls):pass

class Foo2:
    def __init__(self, val):
        # self.val = val, no need that
        def f(arg=val):
            print(arg)
        self.f = f
    @classmethod
    def otherclassmethods(cls):pass
```

I found it's perfect to define a class method inside `__init__` function:

1. in the normal class method I don't need self argument anymore.
2. I don't need setattr to Foo2, and it's encapsulated automatically.
3. Function looks more similar to c++.

If I define all class members inside `__init__` function, and I am more concerned with their real practical effect. Maybe in concept, a closure inside `__init__` is not a class method, but I think it work well as a classmethod. Based on it my question is: what's the difference between defining a class method inside or outside `__init__` function?

Please help me.

Comment: Inside `__init__`, it's *not* a method. It's just a local function.

Comment: @chepner but I have `self.f = f`, it become a closure and work well.

Comment: It won't participate in inheritance.

Comment: Are you asking for *all* differences between the two? Because there are quite some.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Maybe some essential things such as the bottom layer implementation, or some programming language concepts. I can inheritance f once I call superclass __init__ function such as super().__init__(). I found I have a tendency to write any short python class this way.

Comment: If it is a matter of wanting to get rid of `self.name = arg` pattern in short classes, and they mainly store data, use a `dataclass`. Otherwise, doing this will break a lot of assumptions from the Python data model I think. as you can infer from @MisterMiyagi answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method objects are shared between all instances of the class and its subclasses. An "`__init__` method" object is recreated for each instance.

Methods use the same mechanism as `classmethod`s, `staticmethod`s, `property`s or any other descriptor. An "`__init__` method" uses its own unique, non-standard protocol.

Methods may defer to baseclass implementations, and use the default Method-Resolution-Order. An "`__init__` method" needs its own means to access its base implementations.

Methods are bound to their instance only as needed. An "`__init__` method" always exists in a bound state.

Methods have an accessible, qualified name; this makes them `pickle`able and other things.  An "`__init__` method" has no accessible, qualified name, since it is technically local to a function execution.

Methods define the interface of a class and all its instances. An "`__init__` method" only defines the interface of its instances, since it is not visible on the class.

Methods use one set of attributes, namely instance attributes. An "`__init__` method" uses two sets, namely instance attributes and `__init__` closures.

Methods are accessible to the metaclass facilities, e.g. for abstract subclass implementations. An "`__init__` method" is not accessible to the metaclass.

Methods can be distinguished from callable attributes. An "`__init__` method" cannot be distinguished from callable attributes.

Methods use the same mechanism for special methods and regular methods. An "`__init__` method" cannot implement a special method.

Answer (score 2):

A method is a *class* attribute. By defining `f` inside `__init__` and assigning it to an *instance* attribute, you hadn't defined an instance method, just a callable instance attribute.

```
class Foo2:
    def __init__(self, val):
        # self.val = val, no need that
        def f(arg=val):
            print(arg)
        self.f = f


class Bar(Foo2):
    def f(self, arg):
        print("Not called")

b = Bar(3)
b.f()  # outputs 3, not "Not called"
```